# PSPDFKit and IIS Hosting

Tags: angular, webassembly, pspdfkit

I have developed an Angular application for displaying pdf documents to the user. I am using PSPDFKit component (web standalone).

Everything is working correctly on my development machine.

When I deploy the angular application to the IIS (v8) I can't load any pdf document. The error that the IIS is returning is 503 Service Unavailable when application tries to get javascript files from the assets folder (they are part of the PSPDFKit component).

The PSPDFKit is using webassembly, but I don't see any wasm files beeing downloaded from IIS, but on my development machine I can see that wasm file is downloaded.

I have added webassembly extension to the mime type list.

The user has full rights to the folder of the application.

Is there any additional setting in the IIS that is needed for hosting webassembly component.

I have tried changing the location of the PSPDFKit files with no luck.

Tried changing application pool to non managed, but then pool will not start.